# TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Tags: python

I am trying to create a "Chat W PDF" app and I'm facing this issue with pickle.

`TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object`

The issue comes from this part of the code:

```
chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text=text)
    store_name = pdf.name[:-4]  # Get the file name without extension

    if os.path.exists(f'{store_name}.pkl'):
        with open(f"{store_name}.pkl", "rb") as f:
            vectorStores = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
        vectorStore = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embeddings)
        with open(f"{store_name}.pkl", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(vectorStore, f)
```

I followed one guide and removed _thread.RLock, but it still doesn't work.